# CSS position: sticky behaves differently on scroll up and scroll down

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-position, vuex

In my Vue CLI app, I'm applying `position: sticky` on a component. On scroll down, half of the component is incorrectly hidden under the top of the browser, on scroll up however, it works as intended.

Notice how the component appears differently on scroll up vs scroll down. It also happens on my phone (Galaxy S8).

Here is the relevant code:

```
//template
<Stepper :class="{ fixed: hasScrolled }" />

//script
methods: {
  methods: {
    scroll() {
      window.onscroll = () => {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 25) {
          this.$store.dispatch("updateHasScrolled", true);
        }
        if (window.pageYOffset < 25) {
          this.$store.dispatch("updateHasScrolled", false);
        }
      };
    }
  },
  computed: {
    hasScrolled() {
      return this.$store.getters.getHasScrolled;
    }
  }

//style
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .fixed {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

The repo is [hosted here](https://github.com/Am4nzi/plantme).

Comment: When I visit your Heroku site in both the iOS Simulator and Chrome in responsive mode and try scrolling up and down, I don't see anything that looks hidden under the top of the browser.

Comment: I've uploaded a screen recording which demonstrates what's happening: https://storage.googleapis.com/plant-me/Screen%20Recording%202020-08-08%20at%2015.43.44.mov

Notice how the component appears differently on scroll up vs scroll down. It also happens on my phone (Galaxy S8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed through logging `window.pageYOffset` to the console, that instead of it having the value of 0 at the top of the page, instead, it received the value of 0 after scrolling a little down the page. It's almost as if it was treating the top of the window as some arbitrary number of pixels further down.

I still don't know why it was doing that, but I managed to fix this inadvertently by fixing another bug.

I had a button that had a margin that was pushing it out of its container, causing overflow. I removed the margin, and somehow `window.pageYOffset` started behaving as expected, with the value 0 being at the top of the page. Weird one, but glad its resolved.